# Get content of structure Liferay

Tags: structure, liferay-6, assets

I want to get the structure content,
to be more clear I have this structure :

[image]

And I need to make a filter based on this options of "Etablissement" in the asset publisher

I am using Liferay 6.2 ce ga2.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       String structureXSD = "";

        List<DDMStructure> structures =null;
        try {
            structures = DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil.getStructures();
            //get all structures
            for (DDMStructure structureL : structures) {
                if( structureL.getName().indexOf(structureName) > 0){// 0 for empty string
                    structureXSD = structureL.getXsd();
                    break;
                }
            }
```